# Remove b tag within an a tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a html files that contains a lot of elements like that:

```
<p>text<p>
<p>more text<p>
<p>text <a href="#"><b>link1</b></a><p>
<p>text<p>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</uli>
<p>text <a href="#"><b>linkABC</b></a><p>
<p>more text<p>
<a href="#"><b>link here</b></a>
```

The structure of the document may vary.

Is there anyway to remove that `b` tags within `a` tags?
I want to run that html processing using nodejs.

Comment: Have you tried selecting all the a tags and traverse them to see if the innerhtml contains the b tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using pure `JavaScript` for you

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
links.forEach(link => {
  let text = link.querySelector('b').innerText
  link.innerHTML = text
})

// check the updated result
let newLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a')
newLinks.forEach(link => {
  console.log(link)
})
```

```html
<p>text<p>
<p>more text<p>
<p>text <a href="#"><b>link1</b></a><p>
<p>text<p>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</uli>
<p>text <a href="#"><b>linkABC</b></a><p>
<p>more text<p>
<a href="#"><b>link here</b></a>
```

Comment: I have a lot of text within a document, it is not like document with links, I will update the question

Comment: @sreginogemoh It's also working for your code,check my updated answer